# Display onBindViewHolder value in Kotlin Main Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get onBindViewHolder variable value in the main class but I am not sure how to call this variable. Any help is appreciated.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: TestDetailMenuViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    val Testmenudetail = TestMenudetails.get(p1)
    p0?.customView?.itemname.text = Testmenudetail.price.toString()

    var menuname: String = Testmenudetail.menu
    var itemprice: String = Testmenudetail.price.toString()
    //Let's say itemprice=50
}
```

```
class TestMenuDetail() : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var Test1 = itemprice //???
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass the value with the help of intent if you are going from your recyclerview/list item to any activity , otherwise you can send with event / interface.

Comment: @Thunder I am not passing the value to next activity and I am trying to get this value in MainActivity class.

Comment: Any help on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do so:

```
class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<Holder> {
  var itemprice = 0 

  override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: TestDetailMenuViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    val Testmenudetail = TestMenudetails.get(p1)
    p0?.customView?.itemname.text = Testmenudetail.price.toString()

    var menuname: String = Testmenudetail.menu
    var itemprice: String = Testmenudetail.price.toString()
    itemprice=50
  }
}
```

And then:

```
class TestMenuDetail() : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    var itemprice = Adapter().itemprice
  }
}
```

But I don't understand why you need to get variable from you adapter. You need to know that the method `onBindViewHolder` is called frequently and the value `itemprice` will change.

Comment: @Thanks and I used Retrofit instead of GSON.